# jquery: populate dropdown based on text-box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate a dropdown box based on inputs in a text-box on page load and text change. I can populate my dropdown list on page load using below code. Now when I add new text to the text-box, I want that new text to be appended in the dropdown list or if I edit any existing text, the list should be updated. How do I do it?

Here is my code.

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("[id^=id_fields-][id$=_options_0]").load('change',function() {
        init = this.id.match(/id_fields-\d+/);
        choices = $(this).val().split("\n");
        $.each(choices, function(val, text){
             $('[id^='+init+'][id$=-choice_text]').append( new Option(text));               
        });
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: *"... `.load('change'`..."*?! Also note that you not only don't actually *run* the code in your function above, but because you've made it an anonymous function and not saved a reference to it, you've made it impossible to run that code at all.

Comment: `.on('change', functions()`... would trigger the function *on* the *change* in value to the element determined by your selector.

Comment: this code is working fine. it populates the dropdown list at runtime. But if I change '.load('change',function()...' to '.change(function()...' this works only when I make any changes to the textbox. But that creates a separate problem.

Comment: Your code is only running on load due to a funny coincidence.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ac11 Please check http://api.jquery.com/load/ and note that it does not do what you want it to do. It does however call the callback function at the end of it not managing to do what you want it to (which is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
var myFunction = function() {
    init = this.id.match(/id_fields-\d+/);
    choices = $(this).val().split("\n");
    $.each(choices, function(val, text){
         $('[id^='+init+'][id$=-choice_text]').append( new Option(text));               
     });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction.call($("[id^=id_fields-][id$=_options_0]"));    
    $("[id^=id_fields-][id$=_options_0]").on('change',myFunction);
 });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but this doesn't work. myfunction does not get the object.